# How to wait for a specific URL to load before calling a function using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, url, webdriver, webdriverwait

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow, and I'm somewhat new to Selenium and Python.

I wan't a function to be runned when the URL is equal to fx: https://www.example.com.

I have read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36316518/12710400) answer in another discussion, but i didn't quite understand what was going on.

I hope you take the time to answer my question.

Ok, so i have just tried this:

```py
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
time.sleep(4)
driver.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com')

if WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_to_be('https://stackoverflow.com')):
    print('Desired url was rendered within allocated time')
else:
    print('Desired url was not rendered within allocated time')
```

But it did not work. Any ideas?
The console says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/holger/PycharmProjects/waitTest/wait.py", line 15, in <module>
    if WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.url_to_be('https://www.stackoverflow.com')):
  File "/Users/holger/PycharmProjects/waitTest/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: If this is a personal project and you want some code to be run when someone accesses an URL, you might consider using Python Flask, which is really cool too.

Comment: No, i wan't the program to run a function when the previous website redirects to another, that the program should do a task on. All this is run on a webdriver.

Comment: You navigated to "https://www.stackoverflow.com" and then are waiting for the URL to equal "https://stackoverflow.com"... which is not the same URL. Have you tried using the same URL in both places?

Comment: I tried to fix it, but still prints the error message.

Comment: @Holger Did you find the solution, please update. I am facing the same issue

Comment: @harishaaram I was and still am fairly new and inexperienced in python so I didn't get it to work, and also the project I was working on became unimportant to me so I didn't try that much to get it to work. However, if I should try to get it to work, I would try out the answer/solution below by DebanjanB . I hope you can get it to work!

Answer (score 6):

If your usecase is to run a function once the url is equal to `https://www.example.com` you induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with either of the following [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions):

- [`url_changes(url)`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_changes): An expectation for checking the current url which must not be an exact match.

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_changes("https://www.example.com"))
  ```
- [`url_contains(url)`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_contains): An expectation for the URL of the current page to contain specific text.

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_contains("example"))
  ```
- [`url_matches(pattern)`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_matches): An expectation for the URL to match a specific regular expression.

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_matches("a_matching_pattern_of_the_expected_url"))
  ```
- [`url_to_be(url)`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_to_be): An expectation for the URL of the current page to be a specific url.

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_to_be("https://www.example.com"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

However, *WebDriverWait* in conjunction with the above mentioned `expected_conditions` may not guarantee that all the elements within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) are completely loaded.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-function-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleni/50329056#50329056)

---

### Update

To run a function if the *WebDriverWait* returns `True` you can use the following solution:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_to_be("https://www.example.com")))
    print("Desired url was rendered with in allocated time")
    # now you can call the method/function
    # test_me("Holger")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Desired url was not rendered with in allocated time")
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to Wait for a Redirect Chain to Settle using Selenium WebDriver where final page loaded is not predictable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301396/how-to-wait-for-a-redirect-chain-to-settle-using-selenium-webdriver-where-final/47305895#47305895)

Comment: Can you give an example of a usecase for how these should be used?

Comment: @Holger Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: How do i run a function, if it returns True?

Comment: @Holger Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Something went wrong. I have updated question with more details.

Comment: @Holger Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I have already imported WebDriverWait and expected_conditions. the line at which the import for TimeoutException is placed, is greyed out, meaning that it is not being used.

Comment: `except TimeoutException`

Comment: What? I'm not sure what you mean by `except TimeoutException`

Comment: You've dumped the entirety of the url-related methods of EC from the docs for no reason and then used the same EC that OP did... how is this supposed to fix the problem?